# Cannot convert from const T to const T&

Tags: c++

I have a method `void Graph<T>::remove_vertex(const T& t);`
which calls `graph_.get(t);`

`graph_` is of type `List<Vertex*>`
which has a `T& get(const T& t);` method that I'm unable to call.

`List` is my own implementation of `std::list`

The error message I get is:

```
Error   C2664   'T &List<T>::get(const T &) const': cannot convert argument 1 from 'const T' to 'const T &' O2  c:\users\sorn\source\repos\o2\o2\graph.h    80
```

**List.h**

```
#pragma once

template<typename T>
class List
{
public:
    struct Iterator;

    List();
    ~List();

    void push_back(const T&);
    void push_front(const T&);
    void pop_back();
    void pop_front();
    void clear();
    Iterator erase(Iterator it);

    T& front() const;
    T& back() const;
    T& get(const T&) const;
    int size() const;
    bool empty() const;
    Iterator begin();
    Iterator end();
protected:
    struct Link;
    struct Node;

    void unlink(Link*);

    Link* sentinel_;
    int size_;
};

template<typename T>
struct List<T>::Link
{
    Link() : next(this), prev(this) { /**/ }
    Link* next;
    Link* prev;
};

template<typename T>
struct List<T>::Iterator
{
    Iterator() = default;
    Iterator(Node* n) : node(n) {}
    T& operator*() { return node->value; }
    bool operator==(const Iterator& rhs) { return (node->value == rhs.node->value); }
    bool operator!=(const Iterator& rhs) { return (node->value != rhs.node->value); }
    Iterator& operator++()
    { 
        node = static_cast<Node*>(node->next);
        return *this;
    }
private:
    Node* node;
    friend List;
};

template<typename T>
struct List<T>::Node : public Link
{
    Node(const T& v) : value(v) { /**/ }
    T value;
};

template<typename T>
List<T>::List() : size_(0)
{
    sentinel_ = new Link;
}

template<typename T>
List<T>::~List()
{
    clear();
    delete sentinel_;
}

template<typename T>
void List<T>::push_back(const T& t)
{
    Node* n = new Node(t);
    n->next = sentinel_;
    n->prev = sentinel_->prev;
    sentinel_->prev->next = n;
    sentinel_->prev = n;
    ++size_;
}

template<typename T>
void List<T>::push_front(const T& t)
{
    Node* n = new Node(t);
    n->next = sentinel_->next;
    n->prev = sentinel_;
    sentinel_->next->prev = n;
    sentinel_->next = n;
    ++size_;
}

template<typename T>
void List<T>::pop_back()
{
    Link* tmp = sentinel_->prev;
    unlink(tmp);
    delete tmp;
    --size_;
}

template<typename T>
void List<T>::pop_front()
{
    Link* tmp = sentinel_->next;
    unlink(tmp);
    delete tmp;
    --size_;
}

template<typename T>
void List<T>::clear()
{
    while (!empty())
    {
        pop_back();
    }
}

template<typename T>
T& List<T>::get(const T& t) const
{
    for (Iterator it = begin(); it != end(); ++it)
    {
        if (*it == t) return *it;
    }
}

template<typename T>
typename List<T>::Iterator List<T>::erase(Iterator it)
{
    Node* prev = it.node;
    unlink(it.node);
    delete it.node;
    return Iterator(prev);
}

template<typename T>
T& List<T>::front() const
{
    Node* n = static_cast<Node*>(sentinel_->next);
    return n->value;
}

template<typename T>
T& List<T>::back() const
{
    Node* n = static_cast<Node*>(sentinel_->prev);
    return n->value;
}

template<typename T>
int List<T>::size() const
{
    return size_;
}

template<typename T>
bool List<T>::empty() const
{
    return size_ == 0;
}

template<typename T>
typename List<T>::Iterator List<T>::begin()
{
    return Iterator(static_cast<Node*>(sentinel_->next));
}

template<typename T>
typename List<T>::Iterator List<T>::end()
{
    return Iterator(static_cast<Node*>(sentinel_));
}

template<typename T>
void List<T>::unlink(Link* l)
{
    l->next->prev = l->prev;
    l->prev->next = l->next;
    l->next = l;
    l->prev = l;
}
```

**Graph.h**

```
#pragma once

#include "List.h"

template<typename T>
class Graph
{
public:
    ~Graph();

    void print();

    void add_vertex(const T&);
    void remove_vertex(const T&);

    //virtual void add_edge(const T&, const T&, int weight) = 0;
    //virtual void remove_edge(const T&, const T&) = 0;
protected:
    struct Vertex;
    struct Edge;
private:
    List<Vertex*> graph_;
};

template<typename T>
struct Graph<T>::Vertex
{
    Vertex(T t) : value(t) {}
    bool operator==(const Vertex& rhs) { return value == rhs.value; }
    T value;
    List<Edge*> in;
    List<Edge*> out;
};

template<typename T>
struct Graph<T>::Edge
{
    Vertex* destination;
    int weight;
};

template<typename T>
Graph<T>::~Graph()
{
    // TODO:
}

template<typename T>
void Graph<T>::print()
{
    for (Vertex* v : graph_)
    {
        std::cout << v->value << " -> ";
        std::cout << "[in = {";
        for (Edge* e : v->in)
        {
            std::cout << ' ' << e->destination;
        }
        std::cout << " }], ";
        std::cout << "[out = {";
        for (Edge* e : v->out)
        {
            std::cout << ' ' << e->destination;
        }
        std::cout << " }]";
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}

template<typename T>
void Graph<T>::add_vertex(const T& t)
{
    Vertex* v = new Vertex(t);
    graph_.push_back(v);
}

template<typename T>
void Graph<T>::remove_vertex(const T& t)
{
    Vertex* v = graph_.get(t);
    while (!v->out.empty())
    {
        Edge* e = v->out.back();
        Vertex* dest = e->destination;
        auto it = dest->in.begin();
        while (it != dest->in.end())
        {
            Edge* e = *it;
            Vertex* w = dest;
            if (v == w)
                break;
            ++it;
        }
        dest->in.erase(it);
        v->out.pop_back();
    }
    while (!v->in.empty())
    {
        Edge* e = v->in.back();
        Vertex* dest = e->destination;

        auto it = dest->out.begin();
        while (it != dest->out.end())
        {
            Edge* e = *it;
            Vertex* w = e->destination;
            if (v == w)
                break;
            ++it;
        }
        dest->out.erase(it);
        v->in.pop_back();
    }
}
```

Comment: Present your [MCVE].

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I don't know how to reproduce this. Should I just paste all my code?

Comment: post a shortened version of your code that is small enough to reproduce the error.

Comment: No, you should construct a [MCVE] then present it to us if the act of creating it did not reveal the bug. On the page linked above, there is a link to an excellent tutorial on how to do this. It's a debugging skill you must learn!

Comment: And is the error you show *all* what the compiler outputs? There's nothing else? No informational notes?

Comment: @Some programmer dude No, `_graph` is not `const`. Yes it's all the compiler outputs. But `push_back(const T&)` works even though `_graph` is not `const`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I added all the code. It's first line in `remove_vertex`

Comment: Your `List<T>::get` function what does it return is the element is not found? That's a very big *undefined behavior* you have there.

Comment: I asked you _not_ to add all the code.

Comment: Since it's in a const method the iterator type must be const as well. Because `std::list` enforces that. Also you don't have const overloads of begin/end.

Comment: In `return *it` I bet `*it` is a `const T` and you will try to return a `T&` to it which will fail. If not, then your code's const correctness looks questionable. You also have undefined behavior if you don't find the element, since your function will reach the end of it's body without `return`ing anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You somehow seem to have mixed up the template arguments for your `Graph` template and its contained `List<Vertex*>` class.

When you call

```
Vertex* v = graph_.get(t);
```

the type of `t` is probably *not* `Vertex*`. But you call `List<Vertex*>::get(Vertex*&)`. The type of `t` is mismatching with `Vertex*`, which the compiler is telling you (but you don't show the complete error message either, there should be more, for example information about the template types).

Exact how to solve this is very hard to say, since there's not enough information in your question.

Answer (score 0):

It compared the wrong `T`'s together.
I changed the lists template typename to `U` and now it says cannot compare `const T` with `const U&`. So that's the problem.

[image]